# create text file based on filenames and directory - batch

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple `.pdf` files located in one directory.

Example of the file names in the directory`:`test score_test score _9999999999_smith.pdf`.

I need to parse the file name to be: `9999999999|test score|smith|||||||`

And I also need to print the location of the file to a text file with an `@` symbol at the beginning.

So it looks like this in the text file: `@D:\TEMP\test score_test score _9999999999_smith.pdf`

The file output in the text file would be:

> ```
> 9999999999|test score|smith|||||||
> @D:\TEMP\test score_test score _9999999999_smith.pdf
> ```

I only got to as far as outputting the directory and file name to a text file.

Right now I'm just working on adding the `@` to the beginning of the directory/filename.

```
dir /s/b *.pdf > C:\temp\test.txt
```

I've tried this:

```
@echo off
set var1=@
dir *.pdf /b /s  DO ECHO %var1%*.pdf > C:\temp\test.txt
```

I've tried this:

```
dir *.pdf /b /s ren *.pdf     "@"????????????????????????????????????????????????????????.pdf >>     C:\temp\test.txt
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The command `for` resp. `for /f` can do what you want. Your question is a bit ambiguous - are the two strings `test score` always equal and if not which one to choose for the output?

Comment: Thank you.  The test score is not always the same.  I apologize, i would need to pull the second test score or the name after the first _ from the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions
PushD "C:\path\to\your\pdffolder"
Set "FileOut=X:\path\to\LogFile.txt"
:: initially clear Logfile
Type Nul >"%FileOut%"
:: first for enumerates the pdfs, second for /f parses the name
:: to tokens %%A .. %%D delimited by underscore
For %%F in (*.pdf) do For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%A in ("%%~nF"
  ) Do (
>>"%FileOut%" Echo:%%C^|%%B^|%%D^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
>>"%FileOut%" Echo:@%%F
)
```

Sample LogFile.txt

```
8888888888|test score |miller|||||||
@test score_test score _8888888888_miller.pdf
9999999999|test score |smith|||||||
@test score_test score _9999999999_smith.pdf
7777777777|test score |baker|||||||
@test score_test score _7777777777_baker.pdf
```